# How to count divs and append the total to text inside corresponding paragraphs?

Tags: jquery

Lets say that I have 5 divs with class `.1995` and 3 divs with class `.1996` and 9 divs with class `.1997` Etcetera... and lets say I also have the following three paragraphs:

`<p>1995</p>`, `<p>1996</p>` and `<p>1997<p>`.

I would like to count the divs (e.g. with class 1995), and append the outcome (in between brackets) behind the text in the paragraphs. So far I have only been able to write a lot of repetitive code and I believe there must be an easier solution!

I have managed to count the 5 divs with class `.1995` and display the total after the text in the corresponding paragraph. Like so:

```
var totalYear1995 = $('.1995').length;
  $("div > p:contains('1995')").append( '(' + totalYear1995 + ')');
```

This results in `<p>1995(5)</p>` as there are 5 divs with class `.1995`.

As I am working with over 500 years, I'd like to prevent having 500 variables like

`var totalYear1995 = $('.1995').length;`

`var totalYear1996 = $('.1996').length;`

`var totalYear1997 = $('.1997').length;`

...times 500. Yikes!

Is there a shorter way to do this? I am hoping for something along these lines or even shorter:

```
$("div > p:contains('1995')").append( '(' + ($('.1995').length;) + ')');
```

I have no idea to solve this. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm assuming since you have 500 of these on the page, that you are some how generating the markup on the server?  Why can you not do this `(#)` generation there as well?

Comment: Quite embarrassing to admit I am adding all of these "by hand" directly in HTML. I just don't want to count the divs afterwards, and still show the sum of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an array of the years whose classes you want to check, then iterate over it:

```
const yearsFrom1500To1999 = Array.from(
  { length: 500 },
  (_, i) => 1500 + i
);
yearsFrom1500To1999.forEach((year) => {
  const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
  $(`div > p:contains('${year}')`).append(`(${totalYear})`);
});
```

To not add the counter if no year is found, just add an `if` statement before `.append`ing:

```
const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
if (totalYear > 0) {
  $(`div > p:contains('${year}')`).append(`(${totalYear})`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort; works like a charm. Two additional questions.
1: How can I best colour the counters in the paragraphs with jQuery? (I am having trouble targeting the added number in CSS).
2: How would I best approach hiding the counter if the result = (0)?

Comment: To hide the counter, just check if `totalYear !== 0` before `.append`ing. If you want to give the counters a style, append HTML instead of plain text, and then use a selector for the appended HTML, eg `<span class="counter">` and then `.counter { color: green }`

Comment: Closest I've come is `const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length !== 0;` which renders like `1995 (true)` or `1998 (false)` instead of `1995 (5)` or `1995`. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

If you stick a class on the paragraphs that contain the years, then you can just look them up, and then find all the divs that have that year as a class.

```js
$('.year-total').each(function(index, element){
  var year = element.innerText.trim();
  
  element.innerText += ' ('+ document.getElementsByClassName(year).length +')';
});
```

```css
Lets say that I have 5 divs with class .1995 and 3 divs with class .1996 and 9 divs with class .1997 Etcetera... and lets say I also have the following three paragraphs:

<p>1995</p>, <p>1996</p> and <p>1997<p>.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="year-total">1995</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="year-total">1996</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="year-total">1997</p>
</div>

<div class="1995"></div>
<div class="1995"></div>
<div class="1995"></div>
<div class="1995"></div>
<div class="1995"></div>

<div class="1996"></div>
<div class="1996"></div>
<div class="1996"></div>

<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
<div class="1997"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @Taplar, although your suggestion is elegant, I have chosen for the solution that doesn't require me to add classes to my paragraphs. Very best, Jordy

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
    for (var y=1995; y < (1995+500); y++)
    {
        $("div > p:contains('" + y.toString() + "')").append( '(' + ($('.' + y.toString()).length.toString()) + ')');
    }
```

Comment: No need to use `toString()` .   String + Number  returns string anyway

Comment: @charlietfl Thank for your suggestion, I write this answer quick without running it so I use toString() to make sure this work only